# void(os << args). What does void mean in this context?

Tags: c++

I was reading about folding expressions and found an example of what was used before folding expressions:

```
template <class... Ts>
void print_all(std::ostream& os, Ts const&... args) {
    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander{0,
        (void(os << args), 0)...
    };
}
```

The problem is the `void(os << args)` bit. What does void mean in this context? I've already tried to search for this, but it is pretty generic.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: With fold expressions, you no longer need this trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It casts the result of `(os << args)` to `void`. That's it.

This style is used to prevent the very rare overload of `,`(comma) operator since in theory, `<<` can be overloaded for user-defined `args` argument and return something that has overloaded the comma operator for `X, 0` expression. That might break the initialization trick. This way, the code is safe and comma is always used as the ordinary sequencing operator.